# mpdf needs to be downloaded compulsory in android studio webView

Tags: php, android, mpdf

Is there any way I can directly open pdf generated using Mpdf in webview

webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

```
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(p.this);
    pDialog.setTitle("PDF");
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    webview.loadUrl("https://proffitto.com/serverApi/nn.php?var="+sharedPreferences.getString("id",""));
```

Comment: `WebView` has no built-in ability to display a PDF.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58155621/react-native-webview-for-android-not-displaying-pdf-and-word-files/58158874#58158874)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native WebView for Android not displaying PDF and Word files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58155621/react-native-webview-for-android-not-displaying-pdf-and-word-files)