# Microsoft PDF In-browser viewer of PDF Urls (analogous to Google Docs PDF Viewer https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=)

Tags: pdf, ms-office, jspdf

***Google Docs PDF Viewer*** can be invoked on a PDF at a URL using:

> `https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=`

ex:  https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://github.com/pdf-association/pdf20examples/raw/master/Simple%20PDF%202.0%20file.pdf

However, I am having a **terrible issue (occurs all the time, repeatable with probability 1**): ***the pdf viewer displays a blank page instead of the linked PDF***. It goes away after 3-4 refreshes. This is a documented issue on StackOverflow (see thread for Google Community thread):  [Google viewer is opening blank page frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62583248/google-viewer-is-opening-blank-page-frequently)

That thread mentions **there exists a Microsoft PDF Viewer to view PDFs in-browser** equivalent to the one above for Google.

***But what is the URL for this Microsoft PDF Viewer?*** I cannot find it on Google :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was https://view.officeapps.live.com/

which now is a sign in service

https://www.office.com/

For what its worth your link https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://github.com/pdf-association/pdf20examples/raw/master/Simple%20PDF%202.0%20file.pdf ***works for me*** in my Edgy Microsoft by Google browser and in one of my Firefox variants but not the other (pretty but perpetual spinning circle). Its slow in fast Opera, and old Safari here says NO GO!

Interesting if I exclude the google bit the direct link works perfectly in my PDF viewer as a web PDF. and Waterfox wants to download without opening after download, just the same as this Edge is set.