# react-native-pdf file not in PDF format or corrupted

Tags: react-native, pdf, react-native-pdf

I can open the link: https://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf, but when I try with the link: http://94.23.154.57:8081/digital-cert/download-file?id=33FB3234-23EC-472B-AB6F-76436DDCFA45&view=1, I cannot open it. I receive an error message: `Error: cannot create a document: File not in PDF format or corrupted.` I suspect that HTTP might be causing the issue, but the PDF link is returned from the server and I cannot change it to HTTPS

```
import Pdf from 'react-native-pdf';
import {
  View,
} from 'react-native';

const PDFExample = ({route}) => {
  const source = {
    uri: 'http://94.23.154.57:8081/digital-cert/download-file?id=33FB3234-23EC-472B-AB6F-76436DDCFA45&view=1',
    cache: true,
  };
  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Pdf
          trustAllCerts={false}
          source={source}
          onLoadComplete={(numberOfPages, filePath) => {
            console.log(`Number of pages: ${numberOfPages}`);
          }}
          onPageChanged={(page, numberOfPages) => {
            console.log(`Current page: ${page}`);
          }}
          onError={error => {
            console.log(error);
          }}
          onPressLink={uri => {
            console.log(`Link pressed: ${uri}`);
          }}
          style={styles.pdf}
        />
      </View>
)
}
```

Comment: @KJ It’s puzzling because I still can’t open the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF plugin won't open corrupted format PDF, Even I tried downloading and opening `file://` but it did not work for me.

This may also indicate that the backing PDF file is missing or partially downloaded, there are many reasons for PDF file corruption. I found `6` reasons

1. Errors during download
2. Using incompatible software
3. Encoding by some email service providers
4. Hard disk problem
5. Attacks by viruses
6. Opening the same file with different software

If you want to repair PDF then check this [docs](https://www.adobe.com/uk/acrobat/resources/repair-pdf.html#:%7E:text=Head%20to%20the%20location%20where,it%20into%20a%20Word%20document.) by Adobe Repair a Damaged PDF.

And if you do not want to do all these things then you can open the PDF in another way also.

We have three options to open PDF in React Native, the first one you have already done, now you can choose the other two

- react-native-webview
- react-native-file-viewer

If you choose `webview` then check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58158874/11762907) by aytek answer

and you can open the pdf using `file viewer`

**Example:**

```
 const path = FileViewer.open(path, { showOpenWithDialog: true }) // absolute-path-to-my-local-file.
  .then(() => {
    // success
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // error
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect it to be the http vs https you can try this solution to fix that for iOS.

Add the following to your `info.plist` as explained in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38427829/11729637

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

The file is severely corrupt here is the true EOF  (end of file) at about 10% of the download. True file size should be 125062 the rest of the total 1,106,569 bytes should be deleted. Once you delete the HTML scripting it should work perfectly in any PDF viewer.

Download the corrupted file via

```
curl -o download.pdf http://94.23.154.57:8081/digital-cert/download-file?id=33FB3234-23EC-472B-AB6F-76436DDCFA45
```

The easiest correction is "Open With" Acrobat Reader and simply let it rebuild the file on closure, without the trailer full of baggage. Fixed file size then is 124,125 bytes.

[image]