# Display pdf on expo react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a React Native application where I need to display the content of a PDF that I retrieve through an API. I've tried various methods, including using WebView, but I can't get it to work properly. Unfortunately, I can't use native dependencies due to the restrictions of Expo Go. Does anyone have suggestions on how I can achieve rendering a PDF in my React Native application using Expo?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import { IPV4_ADDRESS } from "../views/SiteHome";

export const NodeContent = ({ route }) => {
  const { id, ticket } = route.params;
  const [pdfUrl, setPdfUrl] = useState("");

  const fetchContentNode = async (id, ticket) => {
    const myheaders = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Basic " + ticket,
      },
    };

    const response = await fetch(
      `http://${IPV4_ADDRESS}:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/${id}/content`,
      myheaders
    );

    const pdfUrl = response.url;
    console.log(pdfUrl)
    return pdfUrl;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPdfUrl = async () => {
      const url = await fetchContentNode(id, ticket);
      setPdfUrl(url);
    };
    getPdfUrl();
  }, [id, ticket]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {pdfUrl ? (
        <WebView source={{ uri: pdfUrl }} />
      ) : (
        <Text>Loading PDF...</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```

Are there any alternatives or approaches I can consider to solve this problem?

Sorry for my english

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native WebView for Android not displaying PDF and Word files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58155621/react-native-webview-for-android-not-displaying-pdf-and-word-files)

Answer (score 1):

first make sure you follow **[expo doc](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/)**

then use **[react-native-pdf](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-pdf)** with **[Custom Dev Clients](https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/)** and **[plugins](https://github.com/expo/config-plugins/tree/main/packages/react-native-pdf)**

```
# Using npm
 npm install react-native-pdf react-native-blob-util @config-plugins/react-native-pdf @config-plugins/react-native-blob-util  --save
# or using yarn:
yarn add  react-native-pdf react-native-blob-util @config-plugins/react-native-pdf @config-plugins/react-native-blob-util
```

then add the config

```
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      "@config-plugins/react-native-blob-util",
      "@config-plugins/react-native-pdf"
    ]
  }
}
```

finally build with EAS CLI